# openldap schema import error

Tags: configuration, ldap, openldap

I am trying to import schema in openldap which has been configured in ubuntu machine.

I am trying with below command and getting below error.

Can anyone help me on this.

```
cd /tmp/openldapldif && slaptest -f slapd.conf -F .
65565851 /etc/ldap/schema/schema_SDA.schema: line 18 attributeTypes:: OID could not be expanded: "ptkSMISMPriorities-oid"
slaptest: bad configuration directory!
```

Comment: Look at `line 18` of `/etc/ldap/schema/schema_SDA.schema`. Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.